# Simple android questions

Tags: android

So I've been looking around for android tutorials, help questions, etc.. I keep running into questions or tutorials hard for me to understand.

Here's my questions:

1. When I create an item in the visual designer, piece of code will be created in the .xml.
   How can I get the ID of that item to use it in the .java file later?
2. How can I add callbacks when let's say a button gets clicked?

---

Here's what I have so far:

.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void Button_click_callback() // Where to add the callback in the .xml?
    {
        // How to get button ID and change the text of it? 
            //Knowing this will help me A LOT!
    }
}
```

.xml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="79dp"
android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: Please don't ask multiple (unrelated) questions in one post, and please make your title summarize your post. Thanks.

Comment: @user1667191 You are so lucky that you got answer to your question from **Sir CommonsWare** :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I create an item in the visual designer, piece of code will be created in the .xml. How can I get the ID of that item to use it in the .java file later?

Step #1: Ensure that you have assigned an ID for the widget in the designer (in your XML above, you will see this as `android:id="@+id/button1`)

Step #2: In Java, you can get at the Java object for that widget by calling `findViewById(R.id.button1)` at some appropriate time (e.g., from an `Activity`, sometime after you call `setContentView()`).

> How can I add callbacks when let's say a button gets clicked?

Generally, there is a setter method for this, such as `setOnClickListener()` that you can call on the `Button` you retrieved by `findViewById()`.

In the specific case of click events on widgets hosted by activities, there is also an `android:onClick` attribute you can have in the XML, which supplies the name of a method on your `Activity` that will get called when the widget is clicked, instead of your having to use the setter.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something in response to button click
        }
    });
}
```

All of this is extensively documented on the Android Developer site. You should be looking their for this basic stuff.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use findViewById to get view ids from XML in Java, Make sure that you should declare the ids in views, otherwise it might cause exception which results apps force close
2. If you want call back with xml rather than programatically
   you can declare android:onClick attribute on that Views in layout XML

For example, in your case you need add android:onClick="Button_click_callback" in your

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="79dp"
android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
android:text="Button" 
android:onClick="Button_click_callback"/>
```

then you can use Button_click_callback method for call back in your Activity

```
public void Button_click_callback()
{
}
```

if you want call back programatically with java,
first you have get the view with findViewById and then you can add click listener to that view

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onClickListener and override the onClick method.

```
btn.setOnClickListener.(new View.OnClickListener(){

     @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        //TO DO
    }

});
```

OnClickListener is an interface. And thats why you need to override the OnClick method.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in oncreate method of activity 

//take button id like that
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

//then implement on click listener for  performing action on button

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something in response to button click
    }
});
}

//you can also implements onclicklistener in activity.its interface; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener

//then generate method 
public void onClick(View view) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button button1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void Button_click_callback() {
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
                Log.e("click", "-------------button click");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those two code snippets are equal, just implemented in two different ways.

**Code Implementation**

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myFancyMethod(v);
    }
});

// some more code

public void myFancyMethod(View v) {
    // does something very interesting
}
```

Above is a code implementation of an `OnClickListener`. And this is the XML implementation.

**XML Implementation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- layout elements -->
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:onClick="myFancyMethod" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First Look at your XML file.In code it shows 
    android:id="@+id/button1.

You can edit it on your own name.Same thing you can do to change it though the GUI appear at right side of your design.

You can get your ID using *findViewById(R.id.your id name);* function.

For an Example:
   My button id is *btn1*.In my code I can use that button by getting it's Id as follows:

```
Button btn1=findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

2)You can callback after creating your Button which you have created Before as follows;

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Create your code
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For the call backs - The android component needs to be registered in the calling device . The id of the components has to be unique in the xmls.
Using the unique id the components can be dynamically altered or the call backs can be used.